# Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(stylePreprocessorOptions)

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I try to follow this rule https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#style-preprocessor-options. Unfortunately, I receive the error during build my project. The error is Schema validation failed with the following errors: `Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(stylePreprocessorOptions)`. Could somebody help me?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNsEx.png)

```
"component": {
        "root": "libs/component",
        "sourceRoot": "libs/component/src",
        "projectType": "library",
        "prefix": "lib",
        "architect": {
            "build": {
                "builder": "@nrwl/angular:package",
                "options": {
                    "tsConfig": "libs/component/tsconfig.lib.json",
                    "project": "libs/component/ng-package.json",
                    "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
                        "includePaths": [
                           "libs/component/src/lib/shared/style"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "configurations": {
                    "production": {
                        "tsConfig": "libs/component/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
                    }
                }
            },
            "test": {
```

Comment: Can you share your config?

Comment: Added in my question.